# Block diagram of inverting amplifier

Tags: inverting-amplifier, negative-feedback, block-diagram

I want to draw the block diagram of a generic inverting amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIAajC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Question**: What is the actual block diagram for an inverting amplifier?

Answer (score 3):

Block diagram of inverting amplifier.

[image: Block diagram]

[image: Equation]

If you are interested in a first principles derivation for that first equation (closed loop gain) then see below.

[image: Derivation]

Answer (score 2):

I'd start here with this simple relationship: -

[image]

Then I'd formulate Vx in terms of Vi, Vo, R1 and R2: -

[image]

So the first equation in red becomes \$V_X = \dfrac{-V_O}{A_{OL}}\$ and this equals the 2nd equation in blue hence: -

$$\dfrac{-V_O}{A_{OL}} = (V_O-V_I)\cdot\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}+V_I$$

Drill down and you get: -

$$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I} = \dfrac{\frac{-R_2}{R_1+R_2}}{\frac{1}{A_{OL}}+\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}}$$

And, when A<sub>OL</sub> is very large the gain is -R2/R1. Hope I solved this correctly!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you noted that your "e" is a "current"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eureka! I think I got it. Writing a node equation for \$V_a\$ yields

$$\frac{V_a-V_\text{in}}{R_1} + \frac{V_a-V_o}{R_2} = 0$$

Solving for \$V_a\$ one gets

$$V_a = V_o \cdot \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} + V_\text{in} \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

If you think of \$V_\text{in}\$ as one input and \$ref\$ as another input the block diagram is not that hard to draw. I think it should look like this: -

[image]

As a sanity check let's find the transfer function \$\frac{V_o}{V_\text{in}}\$ via the block diagram. One can write 3 equations, one for each signal.

$$\begin{align*}
e = ref-s_1 \\\\
V_o = eA_0 \\\\
s_1 = V_o \cdot \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} + V_\text{in} \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\end{align*}$$

Solving for the \$e, V_o, s_1\$ gives

$$V_o = -\frac{A_0(R_1ref - V_\text{in}R_2 + R_2ref)}{A_0R_1 + R_1 + R_2} $$

Inserting \$ref = 0\$ (it is ground) the expression reduces to

$$V_o = - \frac{A_0V_\text{in}}{A_0R_1 + R_1 + R_2} $$

Letting \$A_0 \to \infty\$ we finally obtain

$$V_o = -V_\text{in} \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1} $$

$$\frac{V_o}{V_\text{in}} = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}$$

Comment: Great mathematical discovery, Archimedes :-) Now all that is left is to make a technical invention by naming the building blocks and explaining their functions!